# How to get the scores of each detected class, while performing a image classification using custom ibm visual recognition model in node-red?

Tags: websphere, node-red, visual-recognition

I am using a custom IBM visual recognition classifier in node red, but while getting the result for a image, the debug window only shows no of classes detected i.e 'custom_classes: 7'. How can I get the individual scores for different classes detected from the visual recognition node in node-red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the threshold value to zero to see all of the class scores.